# App.xml fails to find my custom convert class

Tags: c#, xaml, customization

My application fails to build on a clean build. The App.xml file fails on lines where I am trying to include custom IConverter subclasses that I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that App.xml gets parsed before any C# gets built. So the compiled classes are not available.  I removed the custom converters from my App.xml
One can get into a trap where you are developing and then decide to add a custom converter and then (after compiling) you add references to it in App.xml.  Then you do a clean build. Kaboom.